Disable a function on focus of dropdown input
I am using the function below to bind scroll events to a slider element, to trigger next/previous slides.
However in certain situations I'd like to disable that function, for instances when dropdowns are in focus, to allow the user to scroll through the dropdown list. And then when the dropdown element is out of focus, I'd like to re-activate my scroll function. How can this be achieved?
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

var onScroll = debounce(function(direction) {
  if (direction == false) {
    $(".slider-next").trigger('tap');
  } else {
    $(".slider-prev").trigger('tap');
  }
}, 100, true);

$('#slider').bind('wheel mousewheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var delta;
  if (typeof event != 'undefined' && event.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.wheelDelta;
  } else {
    delta = -1 * e.originalEvent.deltaY;
  }
  onScroll(delta >= 0);
});

